# bash function return in if statement not working

Tags: bash

I'm trying to refactor this code:

```
if [ $(($1 % 4)) -eq 0 ] && [ $(($1 % 100)) -ne 0 ] || [ $(($1 % 400)) -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo $T
else
    echo $F
fi
```

into something like this:

```
if divisibleBy4 && notDivisibleBy100 || divisibleBy400; then
    echo $T
else
    echo $F
fi
```

note that

```
T="true"
F="false"
```

divisibleBy4 function looks like:

```
divisibleBy4() {
    return  [ $(($1 % 4)) -eq 0 ]
}
```

But I've tried several iterations including what I thought would definitely work.

```
divisibleBy4() {
    if [ $(($1 % 4)) -eq 0  ]; then
    return 1
    else return 0
    fi
}
```

Any idea how to properly fix the syntax so I can refactor these into functions and use them in my if statement?

When testing I'm seeing the error

> syntax error: operand expected (error token is "% 4")

Another thing I tried is, but still doesn't seem to work:

```
INPUT=$1

divisibleBy4() {
    if [ $(($INPUT % 4)) -eq 0  ]; then
         return 1
    else return 0
    fi
}

notDivisibleBy100() {
    if [ $(($INPUT % 100)) -ne 0]; then
         return 1
    else return 0
    fi
}

divisibleBy400() {
    if [ $(($INPUT % 400)) -eq 0  ]; then
         return 1
    else return 0
    fi
}


if divisibleBy4 && notDivisibleBy100 || divisibleBy400; then
    echo $T
else
    echo $F
fi
```

or

```
INPUT=$1

divisibleBy4() {
    return $((!($INPUT %4)))
}
notDivisibleBy100() {
    return $(($INPUT %100))
}
divisibleBy400() {
    return $((!($INPUT %400)))
}

(( divisibleBy4 && notDivisibleBy100 || divisibleBy400 )) && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

Comment: `return` is not exactly like some other language's `return`s. E.g.:
```
divisibleBy4() {
    if  [ $(($1 % 4)) -eq 0 ]; then
      return 5;
    else
      return 17;
    fi
}

$(divisibleBy4 4)
echo $? # prints 5
$(divisibleBy4 19)
echo $? # prints 17
```

Comment: Your latter version works (though your logic is inverted: 0 should be success), it's just that in a function `$1` refers to the function's arguments and not the script's. You'd have to call it as `divisibleBy4 "$1"`. [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net) autodetects this issue.

Comment: @thatotherguy oh that makes sense! But if I add a var `INPUT=$1`

divisibleBy4() {
    if [ $(($INPUT % 4)) -eq 0  ]; then
         return 1
    else return 0
    fi
}

doesn't seem to work

Comment: You seem to imagine that `[` is part of the shell's syntax, and/or that the argument to `return` can be an executable command to evaluate. Both of these are untrue.

Comment: @tripleee is there no way to execute a command and then use the return of that command to evaluate in an if statement?

Comment: That's precisely what the `if` statement itself does; `if command; then ...` If you want to put `command` in a function, that's `func () { command; }` and then you can say `if func; then ...` but clearly that's pointless.

Comment: Thanks all for helping a noob. I've learned a lot from everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, directest answer is to just create functions that consist *only* of the tests themselves:

```
INPUT=$1

divisibleBy4() {
    [ $(($INPUT % 4)) -eq 0  ]
}

notDivisibleBy100() {
    [ $(($INPUT % 100)) -ne 0 ]
}

divisibleBy400() {
    [ $(($INPUT % 400)) -eq 0  ]
}
```

The reason this works is that a function without a `return` will implicitly return the status of the last command in the function; in these cases, that's the test command (note: `[` is a command, even though it doesn't look like one), so the functions just return the result of the test directly.

I'd make at least one change to these, though: they all test the value of the shell variable `INPUT`; it's much better practice to actually pass the data that functions operate on as parameters. Thus, it'd be better to do something like this:

```
divisibleBy4() {
    [ $(($1 % 4)) -eq 0  ]
}

if divisibleBy4 "$1" ...
```

Rather than this:

```
divisibleBy4() {
    [ $(($INPUT % 4)) -eq 0  ]
}

INPUT=$1
if divisibleBy4 ...
```

Note that you can also bundle up the whole leap year check the same way:

```
isLeapYear() {
    [ $(($1 % 4)) -eq 0 ] && [ $(($1 % 100)) -ne 0 ] || [ $(($1 % 400)) -eq 0 ]
}

if isLeapYear "$1"; then
```

Or use the simpler form @Wiimm suggested:

```
isLeapYear() {
    (( !($1%4) && $1%100 || !($1%400) ))
}
```

Also, for the shell variables you do use, lower- or mixed-case is preferred, to avoid accidental conflicts with the many all-caps variable names that have special meanings or functions.

Answer (score 3):

You want to detect a leap year!
A complete other solution using math mode directly:

```
a="$1"; (( !(a%4) && a%100 || !(a%400) )) && echo true || echo false
```

or as if-then-else

```
a="$1";
if (( !(a%4) && a%100 || !(a%400) )); then
    echo true
else
    echo false
```

Comment: haha you're right! That does look look cleaner - it looks like `a%100` would be the opposite of what I want. I get that  `!(a%4)` makes a `0` into a `1` but I guess if it has a remainder like `a%100` then it processes as false or a 0?

Comment: `!x` is equal to 1 if `x` is zero, and `0` if `x` is any other non-zero value.

Comment: Try `for ((a=1890;a<2010;a++)); do (( !(a%4) && a%100 || !(a%400) )) && echo $a; done` and you see, that the expression is ok.

Comment: I see, I get it thanks! Even though this might be a cleaner solution, do you have any insight on the syntax for breaking it up into separate functions so I can call `if divisibleBy4 && notDivisibleBy100 || divisibleBy400; `

Answer (score 0):

Every command sets a result code. If you want to force each calculation to happen in a separate function, you can say

```
divisibleBy4() {
    $((!("$1" % 4)))
}
notDivisibleBy100() {
     $(("$1" %100))
}
divisibleBy400() {
     $((!("$1" %400)))
}

(divisibleBy4 "$1" &&
 notDivisibleBy100 "$1" ||
 divisibleBy400 "$1") &&
echo "true" || echo "false"
```

Breaking up your logic to functions on the subatomic level is not really helping legibility and maintainability, though. Perhaps if you want to make each part reasonably self-domumenting, use comments.

```
is_leap () {
    # Divisible by 4?
    (("$1" % 4 == 0)) || return
    # Not divisible by 100?
    (("$1" % 100 > 0)) && return
    # Divisible by 400?
    (("$1" % 400 == 0))
}
```

... Though the comments seem rather superfluous here.